# Fetch all data with their column using EF and raw query without creating model classes

Tags: sql, mysql, .net, database, entity-framework

I am coding an application for myself (kinda like a phpMyAdmin interface) where I have an input/text that's gonna send a query to the backend (I am using EF and MySQL with Xampp). With this raw query (as a String) I am supposed to execute it with EF and fetch the data + column without creating any model.
I managed to do so but I can't only retrieve the first column of the data, not all the information and not the column names.

```
[HttpPost] public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetResponseFromRawQuery([FromBody] string query) {
            var res =  _context.Database.SqlQueryRaw<string>(query);
            return res;
        }
```

When I tried something like "SELECT * FROM PERSON"
I got only the ids like this [
"1",
"2",
"3",
"4",
"5",
"6"
]

instead of having all the columns (name, sex, age).
Thanks for your help!

Comment: `IEnumerable<string>` would seem to represent a sequence of rows each of which have one string value - where would you expect the other columns to go? Perhaps try `IEnumerable<(string, int, string, DateTime)>` or similar? no idea whether EF supports that, but I know Dapper does, so it seems an "obvious" approach